# Problem with the current in a multiphase buck converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, feedback, pid-controller

I am a student of electrical and computer engineering and am currently working on a project that involves the study of a multiphase buck converter or synchronous buck converter (2 phases, in my case).

[image]

The following table shows the parameters of the converter I'm building.

| Parameter | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Input Voltage | 12 | V |
| Output Voltage | 6 | V |
| Inductor | 3.3 | mH |
| Capacitor | 10 | uF |
| Load Resistance | 20 | ohm |
| Switching Frequency | 20 | kHz |

Therefore, in my project I'm using a closed-loop PI controller to control the output voltage. With the following Arduino code I obtain the desired output voltage but the current only flows through only one phase, instead of half in each 2 phases.

```
// Parâmetros globais
double Kp = 0.00825;                             // Ganho proporcional
double Ki = 50;                                  // Ganho integral
double t = 0.01;                                 // T = 1/fsw = 1/20000 = 5*10^-5 s = 0.05 ms ; t = T/5 = 0.05/5 = 0.01 ms --> 5 amostras
unsigned long last_time;
double proportional = 0.0;
double integrator = 0.0;                         // Variável para armazenar o termo integral anterior
double error_sum = 0.0;                          // Soma acumulada dos erros
double last_error;
double V;
double Vo;
double Vref = 5.0;
double R1 = 30000.0;                             // Resistência do módulo do sensor de tensão
double R2 = 7500.0;                              // Resistência do módulo do sensor de tensão

// Limites do duty cycle PWM
const int dutyCycleMin = 20;                     // Duty cycle é máximo quando OCR1A é 20 = 399*0.05
const int dutyCycleMax = 379;                    // Duty cycle é máximo quando OCR1A é 379 = 399*0.95

void setup() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);                            // Set the PWM pin as output
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);                           // Set the PWM pin as output

  TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1A0) | _BV(COM1B1) | _BV(WGM11);  // Set non-inverted mode for COM1A, inverted mode for COM1B
  TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13) | _BV(CS10);                                // Set Fast PWM mode with prescaler of 1
  ICR1 = 399;                                                     // Set the TOP value for the PWM frequency (16MHz / (1 * 20000) - 1 = 399)
}

// Função para ler o valor da tensão à saída do conversor
double lerTensao() {
  double tensao = analogRead(A0);                // leitura do pino analógico A0
  V = tensao * (Vref / 1024);                    // Conversão da leitura da tensão
  Vo = (V / (R2/(R1 + R2)));                     // Multiplicar por 5 devido ao divisor de tensão do sensor
  return Vo;
}

// Função controlador PI
void PI_control() {
  unsigned long current_time = millis();
  int delta_time = current_time - last_time;

  if(delta_time >= t) {
    double setpoint = 6.0;                       
    double feedback = lerTensao();               
    double error = setpoint - feedback;
    
    // Cálculo do termo proporcional
    proportional = Kp * error;

    // Cálculo do termo integral
    error_sum += error;
    integrator = (Ki*t) * error_sum;

    // Cálculo do duty cycle do PWM
    int dutyCycle = round(proportional + integrator);

    // Restrição do duty cycle dentro dos limites permitidos
    if (dutyCycle > dutyCycleMax) {
     dutyCycle = dutyCycleMax;
    } else if (dutyCycle < dutyCycleMin) {
      dutyCycle = dutyCycleMin;
    }

  last_error = error;
  last_time = current_time;
  OCR1A = dutyCycle;
  OCR1B = dutyCycle;
  }
}

void loop() {
  PI_control();
}
```

To obtain the parameters of the PI controller (Kp and Ki) I used an article where the same parameters are calculated but for a converter with one phase. I don't know if these values change for a two-phase converter.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong so that the current only flows through one phase. If anyone can help me resolve this situation, I'd appreciate it.

José Alves

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to include the following: how do you know that current only flows in one leg?  Which leg has current flowing?  Do you have a way of simultaneously measuring the waveforms at the FET gates?  If so, post a picture of them.  The waveforms at the anodes of D1 and D2 would be good, too.

Comment: Don't you need 2 duty cycle calculations, one for each phase?  Or you need to somehow account for the fact that the duty cycle (PWM ON time) is shared between the two phases?

Comment: You can have a look at my free [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf), there are two, fully compensated, buck multi-phase converters and they run on the demo version with transient and ac responses. For a 2-phase buck small-signal model, the equivalent inductance is the inductance divided by the number of phases, the rest does not change.